# UITableView Cell Drop Shadow Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the following code to give the last cell in my tableview a drop shadow

```
if (indexPath.row == myLastCellNum) {
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
}

else {
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
}
```

You can see in the picture bellow that the bottom of the last cell has a drop shadow. That is what I wanted.

[image]

The issue is that whenever I scroll the tableview up or down, the tableview looks like the image bellow [image]

Here, you see that the separator between the last and second to last cell also has a shadow. This shadow is more pronounced on the device (the pictures are from the simulator).

So my question is, how do I get rid of this extra shadow between the last and second to last cell?

Comment: Are you running that code within "tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:"? If so I think that code should work... maybe also try to set the shadowRadius back to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using this in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, then how about:

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

if (indexPath.row == myLastCellNum) {
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
}
```

That way you are making sure that the cell has no shadow to begin with (for cell reuse), then only giving it a shadow if the if statement is entered.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't do it.

Comment: Can you share your cellForRowAtIndexPath code then please?

Comment: Even if this is the only code, apart from initialization in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, the result is the same.

Comment: Without any further code, it is pretty hard to help you.